# Who was Ribeiro Pacheco, Portuguese journalist in colonial Mozambique during the 1960s/70s?

Tags: identification, portugal, journalism, portuguese-empire

I am stuck in the search for information about Portuguese journalists in colonial Mozambique and would like to ask for help. I've asked the question already on [/Historiaemportugues/ on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HistoriaEmPortugues/comments/12vrt4h/quem_%C3%A9_ribeiro_pacheco_procuro_dados_biogr%C3%A1ficos/), and was recommended to try it here. I hope that's the right place (if not, please recommend where else I could ask).

I am looking for *any* biographical data, such as birth/death date or at least the full name, of a Portuguese journalist mentioned simply as "**Ribeiro Pacheco**".

Ribeiro Pacheco was one of the founders (alongside Ricardo Rangel, José Mota Lopes, Areosa Pena, Rui Cartaxana) of the magazine **Tempo** in 1970, first news magazine of Mozambique and one of the important news outlets in the 1970s and 1980s (see: [Jone, Claudio. "Press and democratic transition in Mozambique 1990-2000."](https://hal.science/hal-00787210/document) or [this blog post](https://aquinobraganca.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/aquino-mota-lopes/))  He must have worked as a journalist before at the colonial daily newspaper "Notícias" and probably left Mozambique around its independence 1975. Pacheco was a member of the magazine's editorial staff.

Almost all Tempo's issues from 1970 until 1980 have been digitized by Aluka and [are available on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/site/struggles-for-freedom/southern-africa/tempo/). His name appears several times in the magazine's issues (I even found a picture of him in one issue), but only as "Ribeiro Pacheco" without further details. Skimming through, the latest issue he's mentioned in is No. 193 (June 1974).

While I've found details about his co-founders, I'm clueless about Ribeiro Pacheco. There's a [VIAF entry on a Portuguese man with the same name](https://viaf.org/viaf/68178976/#Pacheco,_Ribeiro), but I can't tell if they are actually identical. Endless Google searches (+Scholar/Books) gave no results.

I assume Ribeiro Pacheco are his two surnames, as it's not unusual to be called by surname in Portugal/Portuguese language. Unfortunately, both surnames are quite common in Portugal/Brazil.

Where could I find any details about him? Any clue? Ideas?

Thanks

---

*I've found something, but it's only partially helpful:*

Let's assume the VIAF entry mentioned above is a match.

- The entry mentions his authorship of a book called "As virgens da mármore", published in 1994. However, I can't find anything beyond the book info itself. That path doesn't lead any further.
- Among the 4 external sources linked, [only the DNB one has something to add](https://portal.dnb.de/opac.htm?method=simpleSearch&cqlMode=true&query=nid%3D1056545607): it mentions "Minho" as a birth place and "Journalist" as a profession, both without reference. "Minho" is actually not a place, but the northermost region of Portugal (and a river).
- The combination of his name and "Minho" doesn't give out meaningful resulst, except for one: I[n a document of a parlamentary session of the Portuguese Parliament from 1982 about the state of the media the newspaper](https://debates.parlamento.pt/catalogo/r3/dar/s2/02/02/146/1982-10-14?sft=true#p2721) "Correio do Minho" and names of its staff are mentioned. And there's a Ribeiro Pacheco, vice director of the editorial staff.
- However, that info is pretty useless: There's no have a proof it's him, nor does it help me significantly.

[image: Photo of Ribeiro Pacheco in Tempo, no 16, Dec 1971]
[image: Ribeiro Pacheco mentioned as a staff of Tempo]

Comment: You are right. Two surnames.

Comment: How common is the name? I found links to a journalist called Edma Ribeiro Pacheco. From a quick search this person was born in 1996 so can't be your guy (and has a woman's name, so prob not a guy). However it could be a relative.

Comment: https://consultas.plus/lista-de-empresas/rio-grande-do-sul/caxias-do-sul/01219409000166-edma-ribeiro-pacheco/

Comment: https://www.proquest.com/docview/1973981241/abstract/736A2E98F3D54309PQ/1?accountid=14785

Comment: The combination of these 2 surnames seems to pretty common, actually more common than I thought. Your two links are about a Brazilian from Rio Grande do Sul in Brazil. They're not related at all.

Comment: Another option - put that photo through face-recognition search engines like Pimeyes. You'll have to pay for useful info, but most will let you do a free search to show if it puts out any useful results.